# Java Dice rolling program, Why does it not roll 1's?

Tags: java

Created this program for a project im making but I can't seem to figure out why it never gives any 1's in the results. Im kicking myself here because it is probably something simple.

Just for clarity: The program has to roll two separate die 36k times and display the results.

```
import java.util.Random; //Going to need this

public class Dicerolling { //Start Class



public static void main( String[] args) 
{ //Start of Main
    Random randomNumbers = new Random(); // Generates random numbers
    int[] array = new int[ 13 ]; // Declares the array
    int dice1 = 0;
    int dice2;
    int total;

    //Roll the die 36,000 times
    for ( int roll = 1; roll <=36000; roll++ )
        dice1 = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt ( 6 );
        dice2 = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt ( 6 );
        total = dice1+dice2;
        ++array[total];

    System.out.printf( "%s%10s\n", "Face", "Frequency" );

    // outputs array values
    for ( int face = 1; face < array.length; face++ )
        System.out.printf( "%4d%10d\n", face, array[ face ] );

    //There we go

} // end main


}//End of Class
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't give any 1s? You're rolling two dice. The lowest roll you can get is a 2.

Comment: Where are your braces?  This isn't Python, you know.  :P  As written, you'll roll one die 36000 times, and then roll the other one once and record that one roll.

Comment: unless your dice have value of `0` then you can get `1` or even `0`

Comment: @RafaEl True. But these always have a `1+` at the start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comments have answered your question.  It is mathematically impossible for the sum of two dice (conventionally numbered, six-sided) to be 1.

But there is also a serious bug in your program:

```
for ( int roll = 1; roll <=36000; roll++ )
    dice1 = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt ( 6 );
    dice2 = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt ( 6 );
    total = dice1+dice2;
    ++array[total];
```

... is incorrectly indented, and the incorrect indentation is hiding a bug.  The problem is that the "for" loop ends at the first semicolon, and the last 3 statements are NOT part of the loop.

You need to use braces:

```
for ( int roll = 1; roll <=36000; roll++ ) {
    dice1 = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt ( 6 );
    dice2 = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt ( 6 );
    total = dice1+dice2;
    ++array[total];
}
```

---

A couple of general recommendations:

- Always use braces with `if` and loop statements<sup>1</sup>.  That way, you are less likely to fool yourself with incorrectly indented code.
- Use an IDE that indents your code automatically.

<sup>1 - Some people prefer not to do this, but my experience is that the extra "syntactic noise" is a good thing in this case.  Silly mistakes like this can be very difficult to track down when you are working under pressure.</sup>